# Basic LC Circuit: Oscillator or Resonator?

Tags: capacitor, inductor, oscillator, terminology, resonance

Is an LC circuit an oscillator, or resonator? I just want to make sure I'm using the correct terminology. I've been calling it an oscillator, based on the oscillating waveform it generates.

[image: LC]

Someone with more experience  told me that what I've been calling an oscillator is actually a resonator. But I'm not convinced that's accurate.

Here's a few different examples from the collection of "oscillator" circuits that I'd drawn up (at least that's what I had them labelled as); that he was referring to:

[image: Basic LC Oscillator]
[image: Op Amp RLC Oscillator]
[image: Wien Bridge Oscillator]
[image: Transistor Ring Oscillator]
[image: Transformer Oscillator]

Answer (score 1):

Your original circuit had only L and C; for an oscillator, a power source is needed, to overcome the inevitable losses.

A useful oscillator provides an output signal, thus power is continually extracted from the oscillator; a lossless resonator (only LC) thus cannot be an "oscillator".

Comment: Not really. That's not really how it works. It provides an AC output signal for a short period of time. It just takes a bit of noise to get it started. Adding a constant power source (like a battery) in series, makes it far less effective. Adding one between the inductor and capacitor in parallel, and then removing it (like with a switch) can also be effective. The decay in amplitude is relatively rapid either way.

Answer (score 0):

You were given correct advice,

A resonator is passive and the only lossless ones are atomic and the rest 
Eventually decay downwards, while an oscillatior must  be “active”

- Active:  i.e. have some DC energy supplied with amplified feedback